# How can I tell FindsBy to search elements on this particular sites

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, webdriver

I've started learning Selenium Webdriver. It seems pretty easy but I'm not sure how to use PageObject Pattern. I understand the idea, I guess, but I don't know how to map many pages in one project. For example: the site contains many subsites (i.e. login page, create an account page) and I'd like to create PageObject for each of them. When I execute my script, I'm getting messages that elements haven't been found. What should I do? Should I create a separete drviers or what?

Comment: Can you share some code? Otherwise it would just be a bunch of guesses. It could be issues with your selectors, or how you're initializing your elements, or any number of things.

Comment: I was asking about general advice/theory of Selenium Webdriver. Look at @Denis Koreyba answer

Comment: There are a ton of blogs and docs on the web describing POM. You should spend some time googling and reading up. There's even some documentation on the Selenium site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are doing everything correct: create a new object for each page. Create different objects for common elements that are the same on a lot of pages (like footer, header menu, etc.).

Then to combine page objects, first you need to start somewhere. For example from you main page. So use the `MainPageObj` to interact wit the main page. As soon as you navigate to another page you need to use a method in your `MainPageObj` class. 
This method must return a page object of the new page. So if you open a Login page from the main page then your method `OpenLoginPage()` should return `LoginPageObj.`

**Example:** `MainPageObj` and `LoginPageObj` are page object classes.

MainPageObj class has method:

```
public LoginPageObj OpenLoginPage()
{
    LoginButton.Click();
    return new LoginPageObj();
}
```

So use this method in this way:

```
MainPageObj mainPage = new MainPageObj ();
LoginPageObj loginPage = mainPage.OpenLoginPage();
```

Simple?)

If you want to make it more beautifyl then add static class Pages and add static methods for each page object you have to this class. Each method must return a new instance of your specific page object.

**Example:**

```
public static class RealSites
{
    public static class Kinopoisk
    {
        public static Kinopoisk.MainPage MainPage
        {
            get { return new Kinopoisk.MainPage(); }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your tests use it this way:

```
Pages.RealSites.Kinopoisk.MainPage.OpenMoviePage(url);
Pages.RealSites.Kinopoisk.MoviePage.DoSomethigElseMethod();
```

Comment: Okay, I've got it. It is answer for my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link to understand page object model and after this you can also create for your application

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/simple-page-object-model-framework-example

If you want to learn then selenium easy is best site to learn for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the link, very useful